# How to update specific column table value after create migrations Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

currently I want to update my existing table by adding new column. Let's say the column name is `is_active` with default value is true. I create new migrations for this.

Then I want to update specific item within this table so the `is_active` column is changed to false. How to do this without doing this directly to the database so my teammate can also get this changes?

Should I create new seeder and call it within my migration?

Comment: do it in your Up of your migration

Comment: @N69S using seeder or query?

Comment: what seeder, you're updating existing entries, use query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-columns) to add a column to your table:

```
Schema::table('your_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->boolean('is_active');
});
```

Then you can [update](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates) the values of the selected items on your Model:

```
YourModel::where('id', $id)
    ->update(['is_active' => 'false']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make query to update your `is_active` for specific column something like this:

```
Model::where('id', $id)->update(['is_active' => 'false']);
```